# Issue with list in C# -- MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have issue in the following code. Below is my model code

```
public class Comments
{
    public string displayComments { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? dTime { get; set; }

    public int airPortId { get; set; }
}

public class LstComments
{
    private List<Comments> _lstcomment = new List<Comments>();

    public List<Comments> lstCommet
    {
        get
        {
            return _lstcomment;
        }
        set
        {
            _lstcomment = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and in mycontroller am getting data from EF and adding it to the properties in For loop. Code Below

```
Comments com = new Comments();
LstComments savedComments = new LstComments();

AirportEntities airPortEntity = new AirportEntities();

var userComments = from c in airPortEntity.AirportComments
                    select c;

//List<Comments> savedComments = new List<Comments>();

foreach (var item in userComments)
{
    com.displayComments = item.Comments;
    com.dTime = item.Time;

    savedComments.lstCommet.Add(com);            
}
```

My issue is my entire list is getting updated with same records(recently added data)

For eg. foreach 3rd timn updates both 1st and 2nd 3rd item in list with 3rd item data.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: yuck... you have some serious naming convention issues :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You instantiate `Comments` outside of the loop. This means there are a bunch of references to the same comment object on the heap. You need to do

`Comments com = new Comments();`   inside of the foreach. This will create a separate instance on each iteration, instead of just giving the one instance new values.

Comment: @user2067567 If one of our answers helped you, please click the white checkmark next to the answer. It will then turn green. This is accepting the answer as correct so future users with similar problems will know which one worked for you

Comment: Yes Steve. I tried to mark it immediately but the rule is that i need to wait for sometime. Done now :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to instantiate `Comments com = new Comments();` each time in foreach. As for now you just rewrite reference to the same object.

Or which is better to rewrite foreach as:

```
    foreach (var item in userComments)
    {
        savedComments.lstCommet.Add(
           new Comments()
           {
               com.displayComments = item.Comments,
               com.dTime = item.Time
           });  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. tat helped